# My Settings Keep Resetting to Default

Tags: xbox-one, fallout-3

I recently installed Fallout 3 on my Xbox One. I figured the cell load times would probably be shorter than on my 360. They are. Much shorter. That's great.

What's not great is that every time I load up the game I have to set my settings again. All settings reset to default. I have to change the difficulty, re-invert the look, change the audio settings, turn on subtitles, and remap VATS, change look, and sneak. That's annoying.

The game indicates that it is "Saving..." the settings, but they still disappear next time I play.

Why do my settings keep resetting, and how do I make them stick?

Comment: Well, that's pretty annoying. Does it do any sort of 'save animation' when you edit the settings? I know that most games do a quick 'Saving' popup with some sort of progress wheel/bar/etc. when you edit the settings (and I think the disc version of Fallout 3 did this).

Comment: @king14nyr Yeah, it does actually. It says "Saving..." and then those settings are saved until I turn the Xbox off. I haven't actually doublechecked if it's losing power or just exiting the application that resets the options.

Comment: Thanks for adding that detail to your question. It leaves me even more perplexed now, though... I can't think of any reason the "Saving..." dialog would come up if it **wasn't** saving the settings file to permanent storage. I've found people reporting some other funky bugs on the xbox one version, but can't find anything about this. I'll let you know if I find any reason why this isn't working.

Comment: @king14nyr It seems that loading the settings is where it fails, not saving them. Some aspect of initializing things doesn't fire when you load the game, so it is necessary to open the settings from the main menu to force them to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddled around with this for a while last night. I have no idea why it's happening, but I did find a workaround.

If, from the main menu, I first open the Settings menu, before pressing Load or Continue, the Settings menu opens with my saved settings. I can then leave the Settings menu without changing anything, load my game, and the settings are saved.

If I Load or Continue without first opening the Settings menu, then my settings are reset to default.

So, **open the Settings menu from the main menu before loading your saved game**.